# GPS location only onClick button

Tags: android, onclick, gps

I've got problem. I need only one information about location. I want to click on my button, get location and stop GPS. But in my case it gives me informations about location every 5 seconds. It'S possible to make it work, how i want it? Because i want to save data about start of road in sqlite database. So i need only one information about location. Like my first idea, or the most simple thing i can do, was making the time interval larger than five seconds, something like 5 000 000 seconds. But it's not the best solution i think. :)
**this is my code**

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent dbmanager = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AndroidDatabaseManager.class);
            startActivity(dbmanager);
        }
    });



    locLIST = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            gps1.append("\n " + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent1);

        }
    };
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       requestPermissions(new String[]{
               Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.INTERNET
       },10);
        return;
    }else{
        configureButton();
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case 10:
            if (grantResults.length>0&&grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                configureButton();
            return;
    }
}

private void configureButton() {
    buttonGPS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            locman.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 0, locLIST);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: After you get the first location, you just have to set the LocationListener to null.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. But how should i do it, please?